# Generic Method Not Compiling

Tags: java, generics

I'v written a generic method to sort an object of Type T.
My compiler is saying "cannot find symbol : method lte(T).

Any ideas what exactly my problem is?

```
interface Comparable<T>{
        boolean lte(T t);
}

class Sort<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    static <T> void sort(T[] s) {
        for (int i = 0; i<s.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < s.length; j++) {
                if (s[i].lte(s[j])) {
                    T t;
                    t = s[i]; 
                    s[i] = s[j]; 
                    s[j] = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {"Pete","Jill","May","Anne","Tim"};             
        sort(names);
        for (String s:names) 
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your class is extending your own `Comparable`, and not `java.lang.Comparable`?

Comment: `java.lang.String` has no `lte()` method.

Comment: Yea I was told to write a method that sorts objects of type T, where T is introduced in the sort header as a generic type name, and T implements Comparable<T>. Changes should be limited to modifying the header and body of sort. It's supposed to work for the main method I was given.

Answer (score 1):

You've made your `sort` method generic, with *another* `<T>` declaration, but it's not `Comparable`.  Your `sort` method is `static`, so it can't use the class's `<T>`.  In fact, the class's `<T>` isn't used.  Try this:

```
// Not generic here anymore
class Sort {
   // Bound goes here
   static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] s) {
```

Additionally, `String` doesn't extend your `Comparable` interface, so this won't work (`String` doesn't even have an `lte` method, anyway).  You will need to pass in some objects that implement *your* `Comparable`.

At best, it's confusing to name your interface the same name as a built-in (and well-known) interface.  I suggest renaming your `Comparable` interface to something like `Lteable`.

Comment: I'm revising an exercise I got in college last year, this was the question: "The following program prints a sequence of strings in ascending order. Observe that sort sorts arrays of strings only. Rewrite it so that it sorts objects of type T, where T is introduced in the sort header as a generic type name, and T implements Comparable<T>. Changes should be limited to modifying the header and body of sort. "

Comment: In that case, I don't think you want to write your own Comparable interface.  I think they are referring to java.lang.Comparable.  (Strings DO implement java.lang.Comparable.

Comment: @DannyWalsh Then you shouldn't be creating and using your own `Comparable` interface.  Use the existing, built-in `Comparable` interface and use its `compareTo` method instead of creating your own `lte` method.

Comment: Thats pretty much what had me confused. The Comparable interface I included in the question was given to us by the lecturer. It was also used in some other questions.

Comment: @mattforsythe he has to use the interface because the "original" Comparable interface doesn't include a method called `lte`. That said, of course he can use `s[i].compareTo(s[j])>0` instead of `s[i].lte(s[j])`